# What insights can be found by using leverage plots?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-visualization, linear-model, leverage

I'm trying to figure out whether leverage plots can provide valuable information.  See example [here](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Leverage_Plot_Details.shtml).

Comment: You should provide a reference to what leverage plots are.

Answer (score 3):

According to Sall (1990):

> [Leverage plots](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=leverage+plots&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.51773540,d.eWU,pv.xjs.s.en_US.a4Cglxu1uYM.O&biw=1092&bih=514&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=_Y4oUqDsJoLa9ATP-IDIAQ#hl=en&q=leverage+plots&tbm=isch&um=1&imgdii=_) can show the point-by-point composition of the sum of squares for a hypothesis test.

Still according to the author:

> They are valuable in revealing the degree of fit, the parameter estimates, the residuals, a measure of the variance of the fit, influential points, nonfitting points, nonlinearities and even collinearity

Reference:

Sall, J. (1990). Leverage Plots for General Linear Hypotheses. The American Statistician, 44(4), 308–315. doi:10.1080/00031305.1990.10475750